# AJAX alternative of using jQuery form ui

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

Hi everyone I was using the jQuery form plugin to process form submission (found at http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js) on my page but now have to switch to using an purely jQuery AJAX based method (without using any the form plugin but I can use jQuery). What would be the best method of achieving this? I'm having difficulty translating it across. What would an ideal solution look like?

This is the code I'm using at the moment below:

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 

$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    target:        '#result',  
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  
    success:       showResponse   
}; 

// bind to the form's submit event 

$('#booking').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false; 
    }); 
});  

// pre-submit callback 

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    var queryString = $.param(formData); 
    // alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString); 
}

// post-submit callback 

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    $('#last-step').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $('#result').html(responseText).fadeIn(300);
    });
}
```

Comment: You may want to post on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    data: $('form[name="booking"]').serialize(),
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#last-step').fadeOut(300, function() { $('#result').html(data).fadeIn(300);
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        // your code here
    },
    error: function (url, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

- The data param, can be something like this: 'param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3'
- type can be: POST or GET
- dataType can be: json, html, xml..

For more information, refer to this url: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You need to specify the 'url' and 'data', then you have the callbacks.. success, complete and error... so when the request to the url is ok, without errors... .ajax trigger the success function... when the excecution complete, .ajax triggers complete function.. etc.

Comment: How would I apply my current code to your example. The name of the file that processes the form is `process.php`.

Comment: You need to change the 'url' param to this: url: 'process.php' .. what's the name of your form ?

Comment: The name of my form is booking. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: then use: data: $('form[name="booking"]').serialize()

Comment: How about the post-submit callback animation? How would I implement that? i.e. `function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    $('#last-step').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $('#result').html(responseText).fadeIn(300);
    });
}` it is meant to update the div **#last-step** and show the result of the SQL query in **#result**.

Comment: your response is in html? 
datatype: 'html'

and

success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    },

Comment: See the example in my answer. Greatings.